# how to secure Java EE application's files

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have developed a Java EE web application using JSP and servlet.

I have uploaded my application .war file into tomcat 7.0.47 and it's working fine with **localhost:8080/XXX_1-5/**. I have some important images and videos which using in my application so that i should protect from client who's buying this app.

In the server system easily get the whole application from path **/home/XXX/tomcat 7.047/webapps/XXX_1-5**.

How to protect my files after they are deployed to Tomcat?

Comment: Who are you trying to secure the images from? The client or the users. Why don't you try by having you web files inside WEB-INF directory. That way they are protected from direct http requests.

Comment: @ErrorNotFoundException actually i want to protect that files in client system.i have developed my application so i have no idea how to deploy with secure before give to client.

Comment: Please see a similar answer I gave in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625429/is-it-a-security-risk-to-show-a-path-to-a-file-inside-web-inf-java/25625586#25625586

Comment: oh.. but till now i am using all files under WebContent.is this bad way?

Comment: Very..anyone can have access to the files as long as they know the path.. some thing like http://localhost:8080/appl/jsps/somejspfilename.jsp direct access.

Comment: ok fine.so can you please tell me what are things i should do before deploy my application.

Comment: Read some details from here: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=471953

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67446/discussion-between-manivasagam-and-errornotfoundexception).

Answer (score 0):

Please place all you application files including the jsps inside WEB-INF Directory. That way the files are protected from direct http requests. Anytime someone tries to access the files inside WEB-INF directory, http standard error code 404 is shown indicating that the requested resource was not found.

Comment: i think i didnt make you clear,once if i deployed my application into tomcat sever there(/home/XXX/tomcat 7.047/webapps/XXX_1-5) is that deployed project with .war and extracted file so i want to secure my deployed application.

Comment: I think it is the definition of securing and in what ways. Once the files are extracted into the server, they can always be accessed by someone who has access to the server. Alternatively, you can save these files in the database and access them from there.